# Best Way To Reload Element Oriented JS On Element Replace

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

What's the best way to re-initialize javascript without a page refresh
I'm currently trying to append an MDBootstrap `<select>` tag, which is not as simple as adding a child element. Instead I'm removing the element and reconstructing it with the updated data via AJAX request.

At the moment, the only possibility I see is just executing the code again after the element is recreated.

Apologies if this isn't clear enough.

What I'm attempting to try, which works, however it's not very clean:

```
$("#function-btn").click(function(){
    $.get("api/endpoint/getprofiles", function(){}).done(function(data){
        $(".select-wrapper.mdb-select.md-form").remove()
        $("#charcontainer").html(data);
        $('.mdb-select').materialSelect();
    })
    // Reinitialize other JQuery functions around the '.mdb-select' element (alot)
})
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add any relevant code that you have tried. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following html

```html
<div id='wrapper'>
    <div id='container'>
        <span>Content</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you're deleting and replacing `#container` you will not want to hook  your selector on `#container` but rather your jQuery should hook onto the parent (`#wrapper`) *first* and then drill down.

Therefore it will look something like this.

```js
$('#wrapper>#container').on('click',function(){
    //do the thing
});
```

That way you're *technically* not hooking onto the element that's removed from the `DOM` but rather the *parent* (`#wrapper`) element even though the selector has the child.